# verilog adder-subtractor if bug

Tags: debugging, logic, verilog, modelsim, quartus

> Error: Add_sub.v(32): LHS in procedural continuous assignment may not be a net: co.
> Error: Add_sub.v(34): LHS in procedural continuous assignment may not be a net: co.

I want to write a Verilog file for a full adder-subtractor with a selection en (en == 0 is adder and en == 1 is subtractor). I am struggling on the full-adder module FA, I was trying to write an if statement to realize this. But I encountered the errors above.
Below is my code:

```
module Add_sub(x,y,co,u,en);
  input [3:0]x, y;
  input en;
  output [3:0]u;
  output co;

  wire [3:0]a;
  wire [3:1]c;

  xnor(a[0],x[0],en);
  xnor(a[1],x[1],en);
  xnor(a[2],x[2],en);
  xnor(a[3],x[3],en);

  reg co;

  FA M0(y[0],a[0],en,u[0],c[1]);
  FA M1(y[1],a[1],c[1],u[1],c[2]);
  FA M2(y[2],a[2],c[2],u[2],c[3]);
  FA M3(y[3],a[3],c[3],u[3],c[3]);

endmodule

module FA(x,y,cin,u,co,en);
  input x, y, cin, en;
  output u, co;

  assign u = x ^ y ^ cin;

always@(en, x, y, cin) begin
  if (en == 0)
  assign co = (x & y) | (x & cin) | (y & cin);
  if (en == 1)
  assign co = (!x & y) | (!x & cin) | (y & cin);
end

endmodule
```

Can someone help me with this? Or please provide me some other method of the full adder-subtractor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use assign in an always block, and make a variable assigned in as always block a reg like this to fix the FA module.

```
module FA(x,y,cin,u,co,en);
  input x, y, cin, en;
  output reg u, co;

  assign u = x ^ y ^ cin;

always@(en, x, y, cin) begin
  if (en == 0)
    co = (x & y) | (x & cin) | (y & cin);
  if (en == 1)
    co = (!x & y) | (!x & cin) | (y & cin);
end
```

The design has other issues, the FA module has 6 ports, the FA instances have 5 connections.

The design uses positional matching for the instance names against the port names and the position is wrong for the first instance.  The en signal is in the middle of the list in the instance, and end end of the list for the module.  Named association is better than positional for exactly this reason.